# Recyrcleview Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

No meu caso vou precisar colocar vários botões em um recyrcleview tem como reconhecer em que botão foi  clicado ou somente a posição de um item na lista?

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nome"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/divisao"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="LANÇAR" />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma interface que terá um método que será implementado na sua Activity, passar este listener para seu adapter setar o onClickListerner para o seu botão dentro do adapter e chamar o método da interface que você implementou.

**Exemplo**

*Parte 1*

```
public interface OnClickButton{
    void onClick(View view);
}
```

*Parte 2*

```
public class SuaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickButton{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.seu_arquivo_xml);

   seuAdapter.OnClickButton(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   //Aqui você consegue capturar o id da View clicada
   switch(view.getId()){ 
       case R.id.nome:
           //ação
           break;
       default:
           break;
   }
}
```

*Parte 3*

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter .MyViewHolder> {

    private OnClickButton onClickButton;


     public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public Button btNome;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            btNome= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.nome);

            btNome.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onClickButton.onClick(view);
        }
    }
.
.
.
```

Tente esta solução, abraços!

Comment: Muito obrigado cara...